# WebView loading outdated local images. How to update?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I have a `WebView` that just displays an image from the external SD-card. This works well, however if the image is overwritten with new data, the `WebView` does not update the image.

This is even more curious because the `WebView` is created totally new in the `onCreate` method of the activity. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating Viewer");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String imagePath = extras.getString("imgFile");

    shareImage(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)));

    setContentView(R.layout.viewer_test);

    WebView viewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
    viewer.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    viewer.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    viewer.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    viewer.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    viewer.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    String filename = "file://"+ imagePath;
    String html = "<html><head></head><body bgcolor=\"#000000\"><center><img src=\""+ filename + "\"></center></body></html>";
    viewer.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html","utf-8", null);
    viewer.reload();
}
```

The image at the path that is saved in `imagePath` is overwritten by another activity before the path is sent to this activty. The `WebView` however still shows the old image data.

As you can see I already tried to set the cache mode and I tried to manually reload the `WebView`, with no luck unfortunately.

I also checked with a file manager and the image on the SD-card is overwritten with new data. I tried to overwrite the file multiple times, but that doesn't work either. Somehow the image data gets cached somewhere or something. How can I avoid this and load the new data every time?

(Obviously creating a new file with a different filename works fine, but I want to replace the old file.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Webview. but in ordinary websites you can use the querystring to emulate a unique adress, while still loading same image. this is often used on webpages on css files.

example: http://www.webpage.com/image.jpg?cachekey=23456456754
by randomizing the cachekey every time the image loaded, it is treated as a unique image and does not load from cache.

Put a randomized int or string in the end of your filename string

```
Random r = new Random();
int randInt = r.nextInt(8000000-1000000) + 1000000;
String query = "?cachekey=" + randInt ;
String html = "<html><head></head><body bgcolor=\"#000000\"><center><img src=\""+ filename + query "\"></center></body></html>";
```

I have not tested this yet. but it's an idea how to solve it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you! (Can't upvote you yet, because I don't have the reputation, sorry)